# How to create *.app and *.ipa files manually

Tags: cross-compiling, ipa, file-format

Is there a way to create this two type of files manually, on a linux computer? I am reading about this file formats, and found this description of the *.ipa format:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa
```

describing the directory structure and compression method for it. I do not found a description like that for the *.app file format (only this: https://fileinfo.com/extension/app).

Supose for a moment that using cross-compilation, I generate executable files for the platform arm, for instance. If I manage to manually create the *.app file, and put this file inside a manually generated *.ipa file, than I could have an unsigned executable possible to be installed on my iphone using an application like the Cydia Impactor?

Anyone knows if all this is possible? If so, how could be done?

Comment: You cannot build IPA on Linux, at least not on the OS itself.

Comment: I'd just take a "real" .app folder created with Xcode on a mac and then start from there. I think the minimum contents of the .app folder is a "Info.plist" file and an executable file. The plist is an xml file which specifies metadata (app version, display name, permissions, etc.) and where the executable file is located within the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

U cannot create a `.app` or `.iapp` file in linux.
U require a Mac for that.

Comment: Why should this not be possible? In the end, an .app bundle is just a directory with files in it. The original poster did not even require a valid signature (although I don't see why you should not be able to sign it somehow using a valid distribution certificate)